# How to search a table with 80 million records faster?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, query, postgresql-performance

I have a table with about 80 million records, I want to find all the activities of lists and workspaces that a user has access to. So first, I get the ids of the lists and workspaces and then I run the following query:

```
select *, COALESCE("origin_created_at", "created_at") AS "created_at",
  COALESCE("updated_at", "origin_updated_at") AS "updated_at" 
from "activities" 
where ("listId" in (310,214088,219,220,271,222,28434,36046,43233,38236,
  1014787,1017501,1065915,162,399844,399845,395721,824491,400,405,408,
  395873,36,188,178,120,461,1104,27341,27356,83329,29271,158639,482197,
  587679,841589,722320,551,170392,421035,197071,632736,632742,632755,
  632758,673517,155,1231,2691,2695,9092,13783,24273,45765,57909,57938,
  58323,291171,324525,496,5369,54099,54576,98818,569319,1434677,279,
  158821,127,158197,50301,761351,261,438101,159009,643013,158273,58557,
  643867,356252,631758,299145,131,179,156,661,241,260,281,245,438106,
  886,101,72915,90857,144564,166270,230,178981,195046,208561,382159,
  226599,297964,298318,89043,193559,326394,313589,450540,541359,620442,
  323458,628644,643014,261008,650332,689117,847849,672369,932660,382843,
  267000,826590,642775,400339,642875,1282788,1341992,1411789,1515479,
  74018) 
 or "workspaceId" in (137, 81, 111, 424284, 425935, 430658, 84, 163840, 
  3, 4, 281105, 57, 64642, 96660, 38739, 273574, 295312, 79, 213, 
  240478, 424760, 65, 36989)) 
and (("isBulk" = false or "activities"."type" = 0) 
       and "activities"."deprecated_at" is null) 
order by COALESCE("origin_created_at", "created_at") DESC, "id" desc
limit 40;
```

and this the execution plan

```
 Limit  (cost=2446886.55..2446886.65 rows=40 width=1002) (actual time=44452.393..44452.418 rows=40 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2446886.55..2449439.67 rows=1021250 width=1002) (actual time=44452.391..44452.401 rows=40 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (COALESCE(origin_created_at, created_at)) DESC, id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 37kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on activities  (cost=37546.04..2414605.20 rows=1021250 width=1002) (actual time=1043.663..43916.385 rows=568891 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (("listId" = ANY ('{310,214088,219,220,271,222,28434,36046,43233,38236,1014787,1017501,1065915,162,399844,399845,395721,824491,400,405,408,395873,36,188,178,120,461,1104,27341,27356,83329,29271,158639,482197,587679,841589,722320,551,170392,421035,197071,632736,632742,632755,632758,673517,155,1231,2691,2695,9092,13783,24273,45765,57909,57938,58323,291171,324525,496,5369,54099,54576,98818,569319,1434677,279,158821,127,158197,50301,761351,261,438101,159009,643013,158273,58557,643867,356252,631758,299145,131,179,156,661,241,260,281,245,438106,886,101,72915,90857,144564,166270,230,178981,195046,208561,382159,226599,297964,298318,89043,193559,326394,313589,450540,541359,620442,323458,628644,643014,261008,650332,689117,847849,672369,932660,382843,267000,826590,642775,400339,642875,1282788,1341992,1411789,1515479,74018}'::integer[])) OR ("workspaceId" = ANY ('{137,81,111,424284,425935,430658,84,163840,3,4,281105,57,64642,96660,38739,273574,295312,79,213,240478,424760,65,36989}'::integer[])))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 9072392
               Filter: ((deprecated_at IS NULL) AND ((NOT "isBulk") OR (type = 0)))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 113630
               Heap Blocks: exact=41259 lossy=271838
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=37546.04..37546.04 rows=1350377 width=0) (actual time=1032.769..1032.769 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on activities_list_id_index  (cost=0.00..17333.10 rows=617933 width=0) (actual time=118.412..118.412 rows=507019 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ("listId" = ANY ('{310,214088,219,220,271,222,28434,36046,43233,38236,1014787,1017501,1065915,162,399844,399845,395721,824491,400,405,408,395873,36,188,178,120,461,1104,27341,27356,83329,29271,158639,482197,587679,841589,722320,551,170392,421035,197071,632736,632742,632755,632758,673517,155,1231,2691,2695,9092,13783,24273,45765,57909,57938,58323,291171,324525,496,5369,54099,54576,98818,569319,1434677,279,158821,127,158197,50301,761351,261,438101,159009,643013,158273,58557,643867,356252,631758,299145,131,179,156,661,241,260,281,245,438106,886,101,72915,90857,144564,166270,230,178981,195046,208561,382159,226599,297964,298318,89043,193559,326394,313589,450540,541359,620442,323458,628644,643014,261008,650332,689117,847849,672369,932660,382843,267000,826590,642775,400339,642875,1282788,1341992,1411789,1515479,74018}'::integer[]))
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on activities_workspace_id_index  (cost=0.00..19702.32 rows=732444 width=0) (actual time=914.355..914.355 rows=682628 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ("workspaceId" = ANY ('{137,81,111,424284,425935,430658,84,163840,3,4,281105,57,64642,96660,38739,273574,295312,79,213,240478,424760,65,36989}'::integer[]))
 Planning time: 2.882 ms
 Execution time: 44452.871 ms
(17 rows)
```

As stated in the plan PostgreSQL uses "Bitmap Heap Scan" to scan the activities which makes the query slower although both columns are indexed. In total, there are 4 indices on the table, one for each of the following columns: type, listId, workspaceId, organizationId.

How can I make the query faster? Or is there a better way to rewrite the query?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? I am surprised this isn't a parallel plan.

Comment: `or` conditions are notoriously hard to optimize (not only for Postgres). Sometimes turning an `IN ()` condition into a JOIN against a `values ()` clause makes the optimizer choose a better plan

Comment: "which makes the query slower"  Slower than what?

Comment: Please turn on track_io_timing and run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, same request as last time you asked the same question.

Comment: You lead with `SELECT *`. Do you actually need to return *all* columns of the row? Also, missing basic information for a performance question: version of Postgres; exact table and (relevant) index definitions (`CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements); purpose of the query; `LIMIT 40` is for testing? Or pagination? Something else? Please consider [instructions here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Answer (score 2):

That query will get faster if you increase `work_mem` (because then there will be no more "lossy" blocks).

The idea to first select all `id`s from one table and then select rows from another table based on these `id`s is fundamentally wrong. You should instead join the two tables and do the same work with a single query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Laurenz and sorry for the late response. I'm Jesse, a coworker of Alans. I agree that joining the tables feels more natural but in our case it's quite complicated to find the right ids. There is a nested access model (having access to the workspace gives you access to all lists) and you could have indirect access because you are part of a group with access. 
We used to check this in one query and then decided to split it up due to performance problems. Now that we face performance issues again we might have to check if we can go back to joins.

Comment: Also I'll definitely check if we can increase the work_mem

Answer (score 1):

For your query with ...

- a very small `LIMIT 40`
- and not very selective `WHERE` conditions ①

... this partial, multicolumn expression index might work wonders:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON activities (COALESCE(origin_created_at, created_at) DESC, id DESC)
WHERE ("isBulk" = false OR type = 0) AND deprecated_at IS NULL;
```

① Currently, after doing a lot more work than necessary, much of it due to your undersized `work_mem` setting, see:

- ["Recheck Cond:" line in query plans with a bitmap index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/recheck-cond-line-in-query-plans-with-a-bitmap-index-scan/106267)

... `rows=568891` qualify after the *Bitmap Heap Scan*, the *Recheck* and the *Filter* step. After sorting, only 40 (!) of those are returned. On average, out of 80 million rows, every 140th row qualifies.

With the new index, Postgres can just traverse the index matching the sort order of the query until 40 qualifying rows are found. Postgres has to read *140 * 40 = **5600*** rows on avg. Should be *substantially* faster.

It might pay to append `"listId"` and `"workspaceId"` to the index. Makes the index bigger (bad), but we Postgres can filter index tuples *before* going to the heap, where only some odd dead tuples still may have to be filtered, thus reducing heap access to an absolute minimum:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON activities (COALESCE(origin_created_at, created_at) DESC, id DESC, "listId"`, `"workspaceId")
WHERE ("isBulk" = false OR type = 0) AND deprecated_at IS NULL;
```

All of this might fall flat though if you are not telling the whole story.

Related:

- [Postgres sometimes uses inferior index for WHERE a IN (...) ORDER BY b LIMIT N](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249617/postgres-sometimes-uses-inferior-index-for-where-a-in-order-by-b-limit-n/249636#249636)
- [Filter on array text[] and sort on timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154681/filter-on-array-text-and-sort-on-timestamp/155038#155038)
- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query)

#### Asides

`COALESCE(updated_at, origin_updated_at) AS updated_at`? Shouldn't that be `COALESCE(origin_updated_at, updated_at) AS updated_at` to match the logic of `COALESCE(origin_created_at, created_at) AS created_at`?

Consider legal, lower-case identifiers without double-quotes in Postgres to make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I didn't have time to read all the linked resources and try all your suggestions but I did create the suggested index (without workspaceId, listId). It looks very promising so far! I'll do more testing over the next days and get back here with the results.