# Query performance degraded after upgrading Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, upgrade, statistics, postgresql-12

I have a table with several million records in a PostgreSQL 12 database, and after an upgrade from 11 to 12, a few queries started performing horribly. They went from taking ~1 second to ~5 minutes. I tried rebuilding all indexes, vacuuming, and all usual Postgres low-hanging fruit, but performance is still terrible.

This is the query:

```
SELECT id, activity_count
FROM user
WHERE (search_index) @@ (to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', '''1234567890'':*') AND active = true
ORDER BY activity_count DESC LIMIT 101
```

In other words, find all active users matching the given account number, and sort from most active to least.

This query takes about 5 minutes to return just 2 records. Something's not right.

The column `search_index` is a tsvector storing all the keywords from the table's various text fields (just things like account_number, name, etc).

I have a GIN index created for this column with:

```
CREATE INDEX user_search_index_gin
    ON public.user USING gin
    (search_index)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I also have an index for the `active` column with:

```
CREATE INDEX user_active
    ON public.user USING btree
    (active ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

And I have an orderd index for the `activity_count` with:

```
CREATE INDEX user_activity_count
    ON public.user USING btree
    (activity_count ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Yet when I run `EXPLAIN`, I get:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.56..11443.66 rows=101 width=1552)"
"  ->  Index Scan Backward using user_activity_count on user  (cost=0.56..36010185.91 rows=317836 width=1552)"
"        Filter: (active AND (search_index @@ '''1234567890'':*'::tsquery))"
```

Why is it only using the user_activity_count index and not the more efficient GIN index? How do I fix this?

Comment: A bare `EXPLAIN` rarely discloses enough information for performance questions. Show results from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` by default.

Comment: Also: `FROM user` would raise an exception, as `user` is a reserved word. Parentheses are messed up, too. You are not showing your actual query. Please do.

Comment: You can also check the plan generated using `explain (analyze)` and see if Postgres enabled `JIT` for your query. Sadly, more often then not, "jitting" makes things slower. If you see JIT enabled, turn it off: `set jit=off;` before running the query and see if that changes anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Which index to use?

While your `WHERE` conditions are not very selective, the current query plan makes a lot of sense with `ORDER BY activity_count DESC LIMIT 101`. See:

- [How to search a table with 80 million records faster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269775/how-to-search-a-table-with-80-million-records-faster/269835#269835)

However, your predicates strike me as pretty selective:

```
WHERE (search_index) @@ (to_tsquery('pg_catalog.english', '''1234567890'':*') AND active = true
```

That's unless your example `'1234567890'` is misleading. (Are you sure you want the single quotes in the search term?) It's obviously not the actual query you used. Unmatched parentheses. In any case, you probably want the  "simple" text search configuration (plus some improvements):

```
WHERE  search_index @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.simple', '''1234567890'':*')
AND    active
```

See:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157951/get-partial-match-from-gin-indexed-tsvector-column/157982#157982)

#### Statistics

So it seems your statistics are not up to date.

> after an upgrade from 11 to 12, a few queries starting performing
> horribly. They went from taking ~1 second to ~5 minutes. I tried
> rebuilding all indexes, vacuuming, and all usual Postgres low-hanging
> fruit, but performance is still terrible.

> Why is it only using the user_activity_count index and not the more efficient GIN index?

Did you also add [**`ANALYZE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) to your basket of *all usual Postgres low-hanging fruit*? You certainly didn't mention it. Consider [instructions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html):

> 14. Statistics
>
>     Because optimizer statistics are not transferred by `pg_upgrade`, you
>     will be instructed to run a command to regenerate that information at
>     the end of the upgrade. You might need to set connection parameters to
>     match your new cluster.

If your DB is *big*, you may be interested in `vacuumdb` with the option `--analyze-in-stages`. (That ship may have sailed for the case at hand.) [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-vacuumdb.html)

> This option is useful to analyze a database that was newly populated
> from a restored dump or by `pg_upgrade`. This option will try to create
> some statistics as fast as possible, to make the database usable, and
> then produce full statistics in the subsequent stages.

Related:

- [Optimizing slow performance of simple SELECT query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187923/optimizing-slow-performance-of-simple-select-query/187981#187981)

Comment: Yep, I think running ANALYZE on my table to update statistics has fixed it. After that, running EXPLAIN now shows a much more efficient plan and the query runs in under a second. Thanks.