# Using PostgreSQL what is the difference between a smallint and a bool for storing boolean?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

What is the difference between the `smallint` type and the `bool` type for storing boolean values?

This question arose in the comments to [a question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/219704) on Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

***Always*** store boolean data as `boolean`. Only exotic exception imaginable.
Just to address the **storage** angle in addition to what you posted as answer:

`boolean` requires ***1*** byte on disk, `smallint` requires ***2***. But that's not the whole story.

`smallint` (like other integer types and unlike `boolean`) also has special needs for **alignment padding**. It can only start at an even offset from the start of the tuple data. So another byte is consumed every odd time (literally).

In a worst case scenario, when mixing with types that require 8-byte alignment like `bigint` or `timestamp` / `timestamptz`:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(row("char" 'a', FALSE   )) AS char_bool
     , pg_column_size(row("char" 'a', int2 '1')) AS char_int2
     , pg_column_size(row(text 'abcdef', TRUE    , now())) AS text7_bool_ts
     , pg_column_size(row(text 'abcdef', int2 '1', now())) AS text7_int2_ts;  -- worst case
```

```
 char_bool | char_int2 | text7_bool_ts | text7_int2_ts
-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------
        26 |        28 |            40 |            48
```

Details:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)
- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)

If you have *many* `boolean NOT NULL` values and want to optimize space on disk:

- [Should I use the PostgreSQL bit string?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25073/should-i-use-the-postgresql-bit-string/25110#25110)

Comment: It seems strange that an ENUM is 4 bytes, rather than just 1 (assuming it had < 256 values.

Comment: @hayd: Enums can have more than 256 values. You could build your own lookup table with a 1-byte PK column to squeeze out more: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159916/3684

Comment: Thanks, I suspect majority of enums in the wild are a lot small, but this makes sense once you know enums are defined in pg_enum. It's interesting/surprising that the pg_enum table uses real/float4 for enumsortorder.

Answer (score 4):

First, the size of a `smallint` is two bytes which is twice the size of a `bool`:

```
SELECT
  pg_column_size(1::bool) AS "bool"
  , pg_column_size(1::smallint) AS "si";

 bool | si 
------+-----
    1 |   2
```

Let's create a small table with 1000 rows and check it out:

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN x>0.5 THEN 1::smallint ELSE 0::smallint END AS si,
    CASE when x>0.5 THEN true ELSE false END AS b
  FROM ( SELECT random() AS x FROM generate_series(1,1e3) ) AS t;

CREATE INDEX si ON foo (si);
CREATE INDEX b ON foo (b);
```

Now we can see the table with 40kB:

```
test=# \dt+ foo
            List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Size 
--------+------+-------+-------
 public | foo  | table | 40 kB
```

Both indexes are the same size (40kB). And all self-joins (returning 500050 rows in my case) using a seq scan and index scan (with `SET enable_seqscan=off`) complete in the same amount of time:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM foo JOIN foo AS f2 USING (b);
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM foo JOIN foo AS f2 USING (si);
```

So really the benefits are that:

- the col size is one byte smaller
- the table shows bool, rather than smallint which is more descriptive
- eliminates room for error if you store `3`.
- it's likely to work in third party libraries a bit better.
- it permits slightly more terse SQL, `WHERE isEmpty` rather than `WHERE empty = 1`

Comment: The index disk usage will be identical I think for a single int2 vs a single boolean index. But try an `(int4, int2, int2, int2)` vs an `(int4, bool, bool, bool)` index and you'll see a difference.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Feel free to update/improve answer with that other stuff about int4, int2 (etc). Sounds like a good contribution. I know a little bit about that but I'm approaching the limits of my knowledge there. I was just trying to answer a question on gis.se and I figured i'd write it down here since no one else had.

Comment: I assume at some point you cross the pagesize and then every row becomes two pages whereas if you used bool you may not hit that limit as quick? Sounds like a rare occurrence though, and I think it only matters if you pack them next to each other. Ie., `bool int2 bool int2` is the same size as `int2 int2 int2 int2` but `bool bool int int` is smaller than all of them. iirc.

Comment: A `int4-int2-int2-int2` index needs 10 bytes per row (which is larger than 8. `int4-bool-bool-bool` needs 7 bytes (<= 8). I'm not entirely sure but the packing is in multiples of 8. Or it could be page splits, as you say. The order of columns also plays a role, at least in tables. Not sure about indexes.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: All basically true. For btree indexes as well. And mostly for other index types, too. (The storage principles are the same, just some special index features.)