# What is the right data type to store only -1 0 and 1 in postgres column?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance, datatypes

I want to store only 3 states in a column (if it was 2, I would use a boolean)

I considered using an `ENUM('up', 'down', 'none')` but it seems `ENUM`s take some significant space.

Is there a better way to store only -1 0 and 1 in a PostgresQL column?

Comment: Closely related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159090/how-to-store-one-byte-integer-in-postgresql/159916#159916

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to save space, you can use the `"char"` data type. It stores a single byte.

you can cast `integer` or `text` to `"char"`:

```
SELECT 'u'::"char", 'd'::"char", 'n'::"char";

 char | char | char 
------+------+------
 u    | d    | n
(1 row)
```

An enum uses 4 bytes since it is internally stored as a `real`.

You should not use `"char"` with non-ASCII characters!

What you are out to save space, you'll have to take *alignment* into account. The values are always aligned according to the *type alignment*. For example, a `bigint` always has to start at an address that is divisible by 8.

Now if your table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE (
   smallflag "char",
   largenum  bigint
);
```

there will be 7 *padding bytes* between the columns, which would render all the space gains from `"char"` moot.

So place your table columns carefully.

Comment: I love `"char"`, but it should be noted that it's still tagged as "internal" type in the manual, not in the SQL standard and not portable to other RDBMS.

Comment: Absolutely true. Usually scrimping for storage space and portability don't go together so well.

Answer (score 17):

A bit of a hack, but is you make the column nullable you can still use a bool, with a null value as the third value.

Boolean still uses 1 byte in Postgres, though.

Comment: The big problem with using null as a third value is that the join semantics for null are different than for non-null values.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tinyint extension that can store integers from -128 to 127 in a single byte of space, however it currently requires a rewrite to be compatible with postgres version 11 and greater.

https://github.com/umitanuki/tinyint-postgresql

Why this datatype is still unavailable in the main Postgres types has always been a mystery to me.

Comment: I'd rather consider [pguint](https://github.com/petere/pguint) created by Peter Eisentraut (Postgres core developer). The "Discussion" in the Readme section provides some rationale, why you may not want to install additional integer types.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The description in that link is fascinating. It never occured to me that there'd be no concept of extension/inheritance for similar types. Thanks very much for sharing.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not really an expert on Postgresql, but checking the docs you could use [var]char(*n*) as someone suggested. Or if you're comfortable working with bit values you could use [var]bit(*n*) which looks like the smallest possible. The storage size for [var]bit(*n*) is basically the number of bits rounded up to the next byte.

For portability: [var]char(*n*) is (afaik) universally supported, while [var]bit(*n*) is sometimes called [var]binary(n) instead